# Why can't i push to github after cloning heroku repository

Tags: git, heroku, github

After git cloning my heroku repository, it says I' am on master branch but for some reason I cannot push any changes to github. Usually I would just enter 'git push -u origin master', and that command would push everything to my github private repository for my website.

I recently just cloned my heroku app on my ubuntu environemt using the following command:

```
heroku git:clone -a ubbytech
```

after this i added all files, make a commit and pushed everything to my website on heroku with following command:

```
git push heroku master
```

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add error message, please?

Comment: @rebelizant when i enter the following command: 'git push -u orgin master' after cloning from heroku I get the follow error message: 'fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: try entering `git remote -v`. It should show you the list of your remote repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same ref

If there's already some content at `origin/master` different from your local version's history, force push by using the `--force, -f` flag

```
# caution: this cannot be reverted.
git push origin master -f -u
```

Answer (score 3):

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Simply add a remote origin, with the url of your private repo

```
cd /apth/to/local/repo
git remote add origin /url/private/repo
```

Comment: @JosephBourne you need to point it to an empty private repo. If your private repo includes a README or a LICENSE file, it is not empty and you would get that error message

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks alot!